# Using VS2003's Application Center Test tool on another machine

Tags: visual-studio

i have an old PC in which i had installed Visual Studio Ent 2003, which included Application Center Test. Now i'd like to use ACT on a different machine (on Windows 7 64-bit) without installing visual studio on it.

so i tried copying the "c:\program files\Microsoft ACT" from the old machine to the new one and registered actapp.dll and acttest.dll using regsvr32 and followed instructions found [here](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) to make them work in a 64-bit environment.

The application runs, but have two major issues:

1. Recording of http requests does not work
2. if i try to create a new test without recording and run it i get the following error: Invalid namespace (0x8004100e)

Can anyone help please?